# How can i retrive same forgin key value value datas in a single field as a single table data

Tags: mysql

i have table like this

table1

```
nid  |  name 
3      john
```

table2

```
tid | address  | fkey_id
56      city       3
57     street      3
```

result

```
name  | address
```

john      city
             street

how can i get result like this
 i try the below code

```
SELECT name,address
FROM tbl_name
INNER JOIN tbl_address
    ON tbl_name.nid = tbl_address.fkey_id';
```

result
i got json

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "address": "city"
},
{
    "name": "john",
    "address": "street"
},
```

but i want the json result like this

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "address": "street,city"
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.address) AS address
FROM tbl_name t1
INNER JOIN tbl_address t2
    ON t1.nid = t2.fkey_id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: SELECT t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.address) as address
FROM tbl_name t1
INNER JOIN tbl_address t2
    ON t1.nid = t2.fkey_id
GROUP BY t1.name

Answer (score 0):

The actual concept that you need is `GROUP_CONCAT` OF MySQL.

Final query that you required is

`SELECT t1.name,t2.final_address 
FROM tbl_name t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT fkey_id,GROUP_CONCAT(address) as final_address 
        FROM tbl_address 
        GROUP BY fkey_id 
    ) t2 ON t1.nid = t2.fkey_id`